# R ubuntu evince

Tags: r, ubuntu, pdf

Is there any way out here?

Evince is the standard PDF viewer of Ubuntu. The immensely popular platform for statistics, R, started its life as a Linux package. But when I do a plot in R -- vanilla, no frills, no user options -- and save it to PDF, I can never see axis labels, titles etc. In evince, even though they appear in every possible viewer (Acrobat, Foxreader, Sumatra, qpdfview) on any OS. I have included qpdfview as default in `memeapps.list`, but when I double-click a PDF file, I get evince. Is there any help except uninstall evince (which I don't want to do as it helps with other file formats).

Comment: Googling for `ubuntu change default pdf reader` lead me to multiple possible solutions. What have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks to your encouragement, it worked, eventually. For the record, it does NOT work through Open with..., even though an appropriate entry was added to memeaps.list; but it DOES work through Properties..Open with.. I am surprised. I also think the maintainers of evince should make that leeettle  effort and fix the problem, as we are talking major applications used with their defaults, and the user is not supposed to experience difficulties, or be a smart hacker.